# in docker wordpress container I get "curl: (7) Failed to connect" when i try to curl the wordpress website from inside the container

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, curl, docker-compose

#### question :

how can i reach my local wordpress website from inside its docker container, for example with curl ?

from the host, i can enter the url of the website into a browser and it works well

#### context :

- I'm running a docker container to host a local wordpress website
- it is composed of three containers (nginx, mariadb, wordpress), that share a network
- it works well for almost everything, except wordpress cron jobs don't run
- when i ran the crontrol plugin it tells me I have this error :

```
cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: <domain_name>
```

- it's likely not wordpress cron that needs to use curl, but it's a problem if I cannot run `curl <domain_name>` in my docker wordpress, so that's the problem I'm addressing in this question

#### what I've tried :

- i got inside the wordpress container and tried the curl command `curl <domain_name>` (obviously with my real domain name), I got the same error, which i can explain because the domain name of my local website is known on my host machine since i mapped it to 127.0.0.1 in `/etc/hosts`, but my container does not know it
- there i tried different things :

  1. `curl wordpress` (wordpress is the name of my wordpress service)
  2. `curl <domaine_name>` after having mapped the domain name to 127.0.0.1 in the `/etc/hosts` file in the container
  3. `curl <domaine_name>` after having mapped the domain name to 172.20.0.3 (which is another ip address present in this file, and also the one listed as `"IPAddress": "172.20.0.3"` when i run `docker inspect <wordpress-container>` in the host)
- these three methods produced the same new error :

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to wordpress port 80 after 1 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

- and if i run for example `curl --ipv4 -v wordpress` i get this output (and a similar for the 2 other tests, and the same with port 443)

```
* Host wordpress:80 was resolved.
* IPv6: (none)
* IPv4: 172.20.0.3
*   Trying 172.20.0.3:80...
* connect to 172.20.0.3 port 80 from 172.20.0.3 port 59440 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to wordpress port 80 after 1 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection
curl: (7) Failed to connect to wordpress port 80 after 1 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

- of course, other curl calls from inside the container works, ex `curl google.com`

Comment: Why do your cronjobs need to use cURL? If any network issues arise, what makes you think that Wordpress itself is to blame?

Comment: @NicoHaase about the link between cronjobs and curl, I'm not sure, but first i think that wordpres 'cron' jobs are not standard cron jobs, and second it's the error message that i got from the wordpress 'crontrol' plugin that i used to understand why wordpress cronjobs don't work, so i suppose it needs this curl command to work, maybe not ?

Comment: and for the network issue i don't think that wordpress is to blame, did i say that ? I think that docker container is to blame, most likely I am to blame for how i configure them

Comment: it's likely that wordpress cron jobs don't need curl, but the plugin 'crontrol' need it to debug the cron problem, and anyway this curl command should work (my title is not about cron, i just explained the initial situation that lead me here)

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it